# How can you merge sort two list nodes without creating a third?

Tags: sorting, merge

Given two list nodes, I need to implement a merge sort without creating a third list node. So if list node 1 has 1,2,4,6,8 and list node 2 has  3,5,9,11,15, the output should be in the first list node as 1,2,3,4,5,6,8,9,11,15. I'm stuck. It's easy to do with a third list node but I don't know how to reliably do it with two.

Answer (score 0):

Given 2 lists A, B.

Im not sure if your lists are already sorted, but if so just loop though both arrays and insert elements from array B into array A when needed. If B is longer, just append the rest of it (once A has been iterated through) onto A.

Else if, A is longer you're done when B is done looping.

Otherwise you could have an offset and just prepend the sorted data into A, using A[0, offset] as your third array.

Another option would be to append all of B onto A and just sort A in place using normal merge sort.

None of these options require a new array and all of them can be optimized to not take up more memory.